# change map markers via ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

I have a search page which shows listings on one side and their location on a map on otherside. So multiple markers are showing now.. But now i changed the search to use ajax. Now the listings are showing properly. But I can't make the markers working. Could someone tell me how to update the markers via ajax??
Thanks in advance??

**search.html.erb**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs">

        <div id="sidebar">
          <div id="widget" class="sticky">
            <script>
              function initialize() {
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('widget');
                var mapOptions = {
                  <% if @arrRooms.length > 0 %>
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @arrRooms[0].latitude %>, <%= @arrRooms[0].longitude %>),
                  <% else %>
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
                  <% end %>
                  zoom: 14,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

                <% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>

                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= room.latitude %>, <%= room.longitude %>),
                  title: "RoomDuck",
                  labelContent: "<%= room.price %>",
                  map: map,
                  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 43),
                  labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                  labelInBackground: false,
                  icon: pinSymbol('red')
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
                <% end %>
              }
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
              function pinSymbol(color) {
                return {
                  path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                  fillColor: color,
                  fillOpacity: 1,
                  strokeColor: '#000',
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  scale: 1
                };
              }

            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr>
            <div id="listings">
              <%= render 'pages/listings' %>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

**search.js.erb**

```
$("#listings").html("<%= j render("pages/rooms") %>")
```

**_rooms.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Sort By:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ajax_link"><%= sort_link @search, :price, "Price"%></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ajax_link"><%= sort_link @search, :distance, "Distance"%></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default custom-hover">
          <%= link_to room do %>
              <div class="panel-heading preview">
                <%= image_tag room.photos[0].image_url(:original), style: "width: 100%" %>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body custom-line-control text-center">
                <%= room.listing_name %><br>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the map with the new data, clear all markers: `markers[i].setMap(null);` (more information on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove, and recreate the markers array with the new data, just like you did before.

Comment: I created a markers array and push markers to that array for removing later. But as its in the view file how can i delete it from search.js.erb?

Comment: Keep a reference to that array (old markers) or find a way to pull them from the map. Set their map to null (to clear the map), and then create the new markers array with the data you have available on _search.js.erb_. What do you mean by "the required one"?

Comment: that was my mistake..sorry..will try this now..I still cant figure out how to rerun the initialize method which is in my search.html.erb from search.js.erb..